# How can i disable a material UI dropdown in react native?

Tags: react-native, dropdown

I want to call an API on save button, the thing which i need is that i need the disable the dropdown and edit it using a button. 
But i am not able to find how do i disable and edit the '**react-native-material-dropdown**'. How can i make it toggle or change between edit and disable ?

I am not able to find anything on google and in the documentation.

```
<View style={styles.margin}>
    <Dropdown
        textColor={color.textWhiteColor}
        textAlign='center'
        fontSize={14}
        itemCount={4}
        value={prop.current_inventory}
        baseColor={color.textWhiteColor}
        fontWeight='bold'
        fontFamily='Lato'
        textAlign='left'
        left={10}
        top={5}
        dropdownPosition={-3.5}

        pickerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: color.textWhiteColor,
            width: '80%',
            marginLeft: 20
        }}
        containerStyle={{
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: color.headerDropdown,
            width: '100%',
            marginTop: 5
        }}
        onChangeText={(value) => this.checkValue(value, index)}

        itemTextStyle={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
        }}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}

        itemColor='black'
        selectedItemColor='black'
        dropdownOffset={
            { top: 0, left: 0 }}
        data={this.currentInventory}
    />
</View>

<View>
   <TouchableHiglight onPress=   >
      <Text>SAVE</Text>
   </TouchableHiglight>

   <TouchableHiglight onPress=   >
      <Text>EDIT</Text>
   </TouchableHiglight>
</View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing a variable (since this is related to UI, we expect to pass a state) to handle the "disable property". The only thing you have to do is to give your `View` wrapper a prop called `pointerEvents`.

So, it would be like the following:

```
<View style={styles.margin} pointerEvents={isDisabled ? "none" : undefined}>
    <Dropdown
        textColor={color.textWhiteColor}
        textAlign='center'
        fontSize={14}
        itemCount={4}
        value={prop.current_inventory}
        baseColor={color.textWhiteColor}
        fontWeight='bold'
        fontFamily='Lato'
        textAlign='left'
        left={10}
        top={5}
        dropdownPosition={-3.5}

        pickerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: color.textWhiteColor,
            width: '80%',
            marginLeft: 20
        }}
        containerStyle={{
            borderRadius: 10,
            backgroundColor: color.headerDropdown,
            width: '100%',
            marginTop: 5
        }}
        onChangeText={(value) => this.checkValue(value, index)}

        itemTextStyle={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontFamily: 'Lato',
        }}
        inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomColor: 'transparent' }}

        itemColor='black'
        selectedItemColor='black'
        dropdownOffset={
            { top: 0, left: 0 }}
        data={this.currentInventory}
    />
</View>
```

Also, I encourage you to use a linting tool like ESLint, you are repeating the same prop "textAlign" twice.  [See more](https://eslint.org/)

Comment: Actually i tried to do this on click of a button, i am changing the state by true and false but still not able to get the result. Can someone help me do it using state and setstate ? Please. Thanks :)